# Need suggestion to use a laptop with Broken Display

Tags: laptop, display

So I dig out a Samsung NP300E5V-A03IN Laptop (3rd Gen PDC/ 2GB/ 500GB/ DOS /15.6 inch, need some suggestion to use it as its display is broken. Adding the pic of the parts. It powers up, the board is in good condition, fan works, no dent in the pipes of the fan. Hard Disk and its ports are in good condition.

Only things disconnected are the CD drive, wifi and bluetooth and the monitor.
[image: Boadr]

Comment: I'm not sure what's your question?

Comment: well the laptop display is broken and I have listed the things of the laptop which are in a good condition. Since I have not much knowledge in netwroking or connecting to external monitor, so put up a question here. So that I could do it myself, rather handing it some repair shop. All in looking for the answer on how to make the use of it? :)

Comment: Connect an external display and start using it? There's nothing more to it, really. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

The  [techwalla article](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-attach-a-laptop-with-a-broken-screen-to-a-monitor) is very good and covers most things but I can add a couple of tips having had to do this myself recently.

It's clear from your photos that your laptop is an older one with a VGA output. So you need to obtain a male-to-male VGA lead and either a monitor or a PowerPoint projector with a VGA input.

Connect the VGA lead between laptop and monitor and if the monitor is one with both VGA and HDMI input, make sure it is switched to VGA or analogue.

Start up the laptop. This is the tricky bit. If you have had to forcibly shut down the laptop last time it was used, it will now be paused on the 'Windows was not properly shut down' screen and you need to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> once to make it start normally.

There may then be a long delay while it processes any waiting updates (although possibly not if WiFi is disabled), but you should eventually hear a chime to indicate that windows is starting and it should eventually end up at the login screen.

At this point if you're very lucky the monitor may respond, but probably you'll have to press the display toggle which is normally <kbd>Fn</kbd><kbd>F4</kbd> or <kbd>Fn</kbd><kbd>F5</kbd>.

You do have one further option which is to turn on the Narrator by pressing <kbd>Windows</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Windows</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> to get an audible description of what's on the screen.

The good news is that once you've got the laptop to recognise the monitor, it should still recognise it when you restart it.

Good luck!

**Note**

I also tried the laptop with a TV using a VGA-to-HDMI cable, but this didn't work for me.

Comment: Thank you very much, me will give this solution a try and will update. Though it seems more feasbile.